# How access value of the system value using Digital Metaphors ReportBuilder RAP

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I'm using Digital Metaphors ReportBuilder in Delphi 2007.  I'd like to access the system date (the value of the now function in Delphi) using RAP, but get an undeclared identifier error when attempting to compile in the Report Builder designer.  What is the best way to get the system date inside of RAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From RAP.HLP

Delphi = RAP
Date = CurrentDate
Time = CurrentTime
Now  = CurrentDateTime